# Trying to create a dropdown that redirects – can't work out why the redirection isn't working

Tags: javascript, redirect, dropdown

I've tried to create a dropdown list where people can select where they are coming from, and be directed to one of three web pages based on their response. All of the styling works, but I can't for the life of me seem to make the javascript actually function.

This is my styling and html

```
<style>
    
    *,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
    select {

  appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
        color:inherit;
        text-align: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  cursor: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
    
    select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
    
    select {

  outline: none;        
}
    
    :root {
  --select-border: #FFF;
  --select-focus: blue;
  --select-arrow: var#FFF;
}
    
    .select {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 15ch;
  max-width: 30ch;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
        text-align: left;
        color: #FFF;
        font-family: new-hero, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.1;
  
}
    
    .select::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: var #FFF;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0%, 0 0%, 50% 100%);
}
    
    .select {
  display: grid;
}
    
    .select {
  grid-template-areas: "select";
}

select,
.select:after {
  grid-area: select;
}
        
    
    .select {
  align-items: center;
}

.select:after {
  justify-self: end;
}

    
    select:focus + .focus {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border: 2px solid #D22225;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
    
    .select {
  position: relative;
        
    }
    
    
         @import url("https://use.typekit.net/msr6mbn.css");
    

    
    @font-face {
        
    font-family: new-hero, sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
font-style: normal;
        
        font-family: new-hero, sans-serif;
font-weight: 200;
        font-style: normal;}
    
    
    
    option {
        
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFF !important;
        font-family: new-hero, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: normal;
        

    }
    
    .cons_submit{
        border: 2px solid #FFF;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: new-hero, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: normal;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        
    }
    
    .cons_submit:hover{
        border: 2px solid #FFF;
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 20px 40px 20px 40px;
        color: black;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: new-hero, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 800;
        line-height: normal;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
</style>
   


<center>
<div>
    


<center>
<div style="padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px">
    
    

<br>

<label for="standard-select"></label>
<div class="select">
  <select id="standard-select">
      <span class="focus">
          <center>
              <option value="NIL">SELECT HERE</option>
    <option value="FLITWICK">MID BEDFORDSHIRE</option>
    <option value="STEWARTBY">BEDFORD</option>
    <option value="FLITWICK">LUTON</option>
    <option value="FLITWICK">SOUTH WEST BEDFORDSHIRE</option>
    <option value="SHEFFORD">NORTH EAST BEDFORSHIRE</option>
    <option value="SHEFFORD">NORFOLK</option>
    <option value="SHEFFORD">ESSEX</option>
    <option value="FLITWICK">LONDON</option>
    <option value="SHEFFORD">HERTFORDSHIRE</option>
    <option value="STEWARTBY">SUFFOLK</option>
    <option value="STEWARTBY">CAMBRIDGESHIRE</option>
    <option value="FLITWICK">OXFORDSHIRE</option>
    <option value="STEWARTBY">BUCKINGHAMSHIRE</option>
    <option value="STEWARTBY">NORTHAMPTONSHIRE</option>
    <option value="FLITWICK">OTHER</option>           

              </center>

          </span>
  </select>

    
    
</div>
    <br>
    <center>
<button class="cons_submit" type="button" id="button" ><em>SUBMIT</em></button>
    </center>



<script src="https://aaf1a18515da0e792f78-c27fdabe952dfc357fe25ebf5c8897ee.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/2266/MB_dropdown_commiteerooms_updated.js?v=1696765982000"></script>

    </div>
</center>

<br><br><br>
    
        </div>
</center>
```

This is the javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById('site');

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){
    var value = select.value
    if (value == "SHEFFORD")
    {
        window.location.href = "SHEFFORDLINK";
    }
    
    else if (value == "STEWARTBY")
    {
        window.location.href = "STEWARTBYLINK";
    }
    
    else if (value == "FLITWICK")
    {
        window.location.href = "FLITWICKLINK";
    }

    
};
```

Comment: Where is the element with `id="site"`? Did you mean `"standard-select"`?

Comment: That's fixed it, thank you so much! @iamdlm

Comment: Feel free to delete the question